# Type markers for hinting otherwise inferred literal object type

Tags: typescript

I am creating a function that takes the config, a literal object of a very variable structure, and then outputs something of equally variable structure, depending on the config type. I want to use TypeScript inferrence as much as possible to detect the type of the config, but I also need the user of the function to be able to *hint* some parts of it.

This does what I need:

```
type Type<T> = (_: T) => T;
const type =<T>(): Type<T> => T => T;

type ListConfig<T> = {
    itemType: Type<T>;
}

type Config = {
    [name: string]: ListConfig<any>; 
}

type ItemType<L> = L extends ListConfig<infer T> ? T : never;

const createLists = <C extends Config>(
    cfg: C
): { [K in keyof C]: Array<ItemType<C[K]>> } => {
    return {} as any;
}

const config = {
    numbers: {
        itemType: type<number>(),
    },
    strings: {
        itemType: type<string>(),
    }
};

// This is correctly inferred as { numbers: number[], strings: string[] }
const lists = createLists(config);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Type%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(_%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Aconst%20type%20%3D%3CT%3E()%3A%20Type%3CT%3E%20%3D%3E%20T%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ListConfig%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20itemType%3A%20Type%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ListConfig%3Cany%3E%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ItemType%3CL%3E%20%3D%20L%20extends%20ListConfig%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createLists%20%3D%20%3CC%20extends%20Config%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cfg%3A%20C%0D%0A)%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20C%5D%3A%20Array%3CItemType%3CC%5BK%5D%3E%3E%20%7D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numbers%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20itemType%3A%20type%3Cnumber%3E()%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20strings%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20itemType%3A%20type%3Cstring%3E()%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20correctly%20inferred%20as%20%7B%20numbers%3A%20number%5B%5D%2C%20strings%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20lists%20%3D%20createLists(config)%3B%0D%0A)

Note the `itemType`s, which exist simply to hint the return type of `createLists`. The above works, but also feels quite hacky - I'm creating the functions just to give TypeScript knowledge about the intended types.

**What is the cleanest solution for that?**

I was hoping for the solution along the lines of

```
type ListConfig<T> = {
}

type Config = {
    [name: string]: ListConfig<any>; 
}

type ItemType<L> = L extends ListConfig<infer T> ? T : never;

const createLists = <C extends Config>(
    cfg: C
): { [K in keyof C]: Array<ItemType<C[K]>> } => {
    return {} as any;
}

const listOf = <T, C extends ListConfig<T>>(c: C): C => c;

const config = {
    numbers: listOf<number>({ // <-- error here
        somOtherPartOfTheListConfig: "foo",
    }),
    strings: listOf<string>({}), // <-- error here
};

// This is correctly inferred as { numbers: number[], strings: string[] }
const lists = createLists(config);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ListConfig%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ListConfig%3Cany%3E%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ItemType%3CL%3E%20%3D%20L%20extends%20ListConfig%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20createLists%20%3D%20%3CC%20extends%20Config%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cfg%3A%20C%0D%0A)%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20C%5D%3A%20Array%3CItemType%3CC%5BK%5D%3E%3E%20%7D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20listOf%20%3D%20%3CT%2C%20C%20extends%20ListConfig%3CT%3E%3E(c%3A%20C)%3A%20C%20%3D%3E%20c%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20config%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numbers%3A%20listOf%3Cnumber%3E(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20somOtherPartOfTheListConfig%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20strings%3A%20listOf%3Cstring%3E(%7B%7D)%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20is%20correctly%20inferred%20as%20%7B%20numbers%3A%20number%5B%5D%2C%20strings%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20lists%20%3D%20createLists(config)%3B%0D%0A)

However, I would still like to have the type of `config[K]` inferred by typescript (other than the item type), so for that to work I'd need [partial type argument inferrence](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).

EDIT: What I'm working on is a library to simplify creating Redux store/action. So basically I want to provide `State<T>` and `createRedux` allowing me doing this:

```
const myConfig = {
  $combine: {
    listOfNumbers: {
      $preset: 'list' as 'list',
      $item: {
        $type: {
          $itemType: type<string>(),
        }
      },
    }
  }
};

type MyState = State<typeof myConfig>;
// MyState == { listOfNumbers: string[] }
const { Actions } = createRedux(myConfig);
// typeof Actions == {
//   listOfNumbers: {
//     push: (item: string) => ReduxAction
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Why do you want `ListConfig<T>` to be empty and not structurally dependent on `T`?  That is [unlikely to work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---) for you.  Isn't there anything of type `T` involved?  If not, what's the use case?

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks. TypeScript does seem to use my hinted type when inferring the type of the literal object, even when the hinted type is not related to the structure. In particular, the type of `lists` is inferred as expected in my second snippet if I use
```
`numbers: listOf<number, ListConfig<number>>({someOtherPartOfTheListConfig: "foo"})`
I don't know how stable that is, but it doesn't work for me either way - I need other parts of ListConfig to be inferred. I described my use case in the question.

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  I'd probably have ended up with something like your first working example, too.  Unless, of course, you have some fixed set of list types you want to support (e.g., just `string` and `number`), in which case I might have a mapping from type names to types (e.g., `{string: string, number: number}`) and require the config use the name for the value of `itemType`.

Comment: Thanks. I want this to be rather generic, but I will consider having nicer interface ("string" | "number" | ...) for basic usage and another field for custom types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you really want to proceed here, since there's fundamentally nothing at runtime that cares about the types you are using, right?  If you had initial array contents, or a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) or some other runtime artifact, I'd have something concrete to suggest.

---

One possible way forward is to represent a mapping from type names to types and require the config to use these names:

```
interface TypeNames {
  string: string,
  number: number,
  boolean: boolean,
  arrayOfStrings: string[],
  // etc
}

type ListConfig<K extends keyof TypeNames> = {
  itemType: K
}

type Config = {
  [name: string]: ListConfig<keyof TypeNames>;
}

const createLists = <C extends Config>(
  cfg: C
): { [K in keyof C]: Array<TypeNames[C[K]['itemType']]> } => {
  return {} as any;
}

// This is correctly inferred as { numbers: number[], strings: string[] }
const lists = createLists({
  numbers: { itemType: "number", otherStuff: "foo" },
  strings: { itemType: "string", otherStuff: 1234 }
});
```

This works as far as it goes, but requires a fixed (possibly extendible) list of types.

---

Another way to go is to ask the caller to `createLists()` to specify an object type for the type parameter, whose keys match the keys of the config, and whose values are the relevant list types:

```
const createLists = <T>() => <C extends Record<keyof T, any>>(
  cfg: C
): { [K in keyof C]: K extends keyof T ? Array<T[K]> : any } => {
  return {} as any;
}

// This is correctly inferred as { numbers: number[], strings: string[] }
const lists = createLists<{ numbers: number, strings: string }>()({
  numbers: { otherStuff: "foo" },
  strings: { otherStuff: 1234 }  
});
```

(Note the [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function in the absence of partial type inference.) That's a *little* bit redundant, as you need to specify the `numbers` and `strings` keys twice, but it feels a lot cleaner to me.

---

Anyway, hope those give you some ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I like the currying suggestion, as it allows hiding the dirt of the first solution with `const withItemType = <T>() => <C>(c: C) => ({...c, itemType: type<T>()});` and `strings: withItemType<string>()({})`

As for the way to proceed, I don't care that much about typechecking inside my `createRedux` method. I just want to provide nice types for the users of it :)

Comment: FWIW. the solution I landed on was to ditch inferring all the types from the provided blob, and instead have them explicitly listed as class type arguments, updated piece by piece using builder pattern: https://github.com/maciekwawro/redux-compact/blob/master/src/lib/definition.ts#L43